# How do I insert a tab character in Iterm?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, iterm

Simply put, I know you can do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to insert a physically real tab character in a bash statement. But how do I do the same for iTerm?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The answer was to hit control+v, then tab afterwards, not all together! Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

It's not iTerm, but your shell that affects how you''re able to insert a tab.

First, make sure you're in BASH shell: Type the following command:

```
$ echo $RANDOM $BASH_VERSINFO
23714 3
```

The first is a random number, and the second should be the BASH Version number. If you get a blank line or just a random number, you're not in the BASH shell, and that's probably one of your issues.

Another thing is to execute this command:

```
$ set -o
allexport       off
braceexpand     on
emacs           on
errexit         off
errtrace        off
[...]
privileged      off
verbose         off
vi              off
trace           off
```

The two lines of interest is the *emacs* and the *vi* lines. One of those should be *on*. If they're both off, you can't do the *Ctrl-V-Tab* to insert a tab character.

When the `vi` mode is on, it should be *Ctrl-V-Tab* like you said. With `emacs` mode on, it is either *Ctrl-V-tab*, or possibly *Ctrl-Q-tab*.

However, this isn't an `iTerm` thing, this is your shell that's doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If by a "physically real tab character" you mean sending the tab [hex code](http://www.pcguide.com/res/tablesASCII-c.html) (0x09) to the shell, then you can do this in iTerm by pressing Ctrl + Tab (⌃ ⇥).

This is the default setting, although you can change it (as well as add other hex code values to send) in iTerm > Preferences > Profiles > Keys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain why you're comparing a "bash statement" with iTerm.  You write bash scripts in iTerm.  Which means, assuming you're writing your scripts in iTerm, you're already doing what you want.

I'll assume you mean scripting in vi vs command line.  The way I get literal characters on the command line is by using [vi editing mode](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/).  Do `set -o vi`.  Then you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>tab</kbd> in the manner that you're used to.

IMO, using vi editing mode comes with a slew of other pluses like searching your history, faster navigation, etc.  So you could just add it to your `.bashrc` if you wanted and use it all the time.

Comment: Say i need to make a variable that has tabs in it, the I would need to do it like: `var='hello[tab]Tim'`. I am doing this on the command line, not just in vi.

Answer (score 0):

One should also try Ctl + V Ctl + I. It is working in konsole where Ctl+V+Tab deosn't work.