# How to specify tab char as delimiter for Export-Csv (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell

A complete newbie with PowerShell here. I need to export data as a tab-delimited file and it looks like Export-Csv is the utility to use. I can't figure out how to specify the tab character though. I have tried

```
Export-Csv -Delimiter \t
```

and

```
Export-Csv -Delimiter "\t"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I type a TAB character in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691068/how-do-i-type-a-tab-character-in-powershell)

Comment: You're using the wrong escape character.  You need to specify the grave accent in double-quotes (so it's not interpreted as a string literal).  `"\`t"`

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer here: [How do I type a TAB character in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691068/how-do-i-type-a-tab-character-in-powershell).

Basically use "`t" (back-tick t in double quotes) to specify a tab in PS.

Comment: Not quite the same as he's not trying to type a tab character, but needs to use a tab escape character.  His mistake is simple, he doesn't know what the escape character is in PowerShell: `\``